# How do I find SteamID's of players on a server I do not have RCON to?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I am trying to find a way to find all the SteamID's of all players on a server, to which I do not have RCON (so i can't run status, unfortunately). Eventually I would also like to check these ID's for previous logins, but this is not required at this point. I only want to be able to fetch the steamID's online on a server.

I am aware it could be done very primitively, by getting steam names, and then going from there to get the ID, however this does not work when there are duplicate names, which will be a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible, unfortunately. Myself and others have done a lot of digging and the most you can get back is what the A2S protocol returns. https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries